# entities.SaveChanges() taking lot of time and entities.SaveChangesAsync() not helping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, savechanges

Using MVC4, Entity Framework with MySQL server I am executing **entities.SaveChanges()** to add a new entity (Record). But it is taking about 15-20 seconds to execute successfully.

When I replaced it with:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    entities.SaveChangesAsync();
});
```

The code executed without any error however the changes were not occuring in the database.

The complete code for the ActionResult in the Controller is:

```
MySQLContext entities = new MySQLContext();
ul = new userlesson();
courselesson cl = GlobalVariables.CourseLesson(intLessonID);  //entities.courselessons.Where(m => m.LessonID == intLessonID).SingleOrDefault();
if (Request.IsAuthenticated  || intLessonID==1)
{
    ul.LessonID = intLessonID;
    ul.UniqueAssesmentID =GlobalVariables.AssesmentID();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Email))
    {
        ul.Email = UserManager.User.Email;
    }

    FillCourseLessonToUserLesson(ref cl, ref ul, ul.UniqueAssesmentID);
    entities.userlessons.Add(ul);

    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        entities.SaveChanges();  // Taking almost 20 sec
    }

    return View(ul);
}
```

The database is in a windows shared hosting server and is relatively small in size (<10mb)

Comment: Where is your database? At remote server? Something could be wrong with your connection or remote machine.

Comment: What is your actual problem? the async call not working or the fact that it takes 20 seconds to commit? if its the latter, you need to supply more information, such as where is this DB sitting, how large is it? how big is the entity you're trying to insert, etc.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the `userlesson` table that may be causing this?

Comment: How big is the user table too? i.e. millions of records?

Comment: The question is clear. In one case it is working in 20 sec and in another case it is not working at all but no errors displayed. The MYSQL database is in remote server and it is small in size. The entity I am trying to insert is also small in size(only few kb)